# The Term Bulls and Bears?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-markets

My thought is that a bull pushes up while a bear swipes down.  Is that where the terms come from?  Bull market and bear market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/129.asp):

> First of all, let's remember that bears are sluggish and bulls
>   spirited and burly. The terms are used to describe general actions and
>   attitudes, or sentiment, either of an individual (bear and bull) or
>   the market. A bear market refers to a decline in prices, usually for a
>   period of a few months, in a single security or asset, group of
>   securities or the securities market as a whole. A bull market is when
>   prices are rising.
>
> The actual origins of these expressions are unclear. Here are two of
>   the most frequent explanations given:
>
> The terms "bear" and "bull" are thought to derive from the way in
>   which each animal attacks its opponents. That is, a bull will thrust
>   its horns up into the air, while a bear will swipe down. These actions
>   were then related metaphorically to the movement of a market: if the
>   trend was up, it was considered a bull market; if the trend was down,
>   it was a bear market.
>
> Historically, the middlemen in the sale of bearskins would sell skins
>   they had yet to receive. As such, they would speculate on the future
>   purchase price of these skins from the trappers, hoping they would
>   drop. The trappers would profit from a spread - the difference between
>   the cost price and the selling price. These middlemen became known as
>   "bears", short for bearskin jobbers, and the term stuck for describing
>   a downturn in the market. Conversely, because bears and bulls were
>   widely considered to be opposites due to the once-popular blood sport
>   of bull-and-bear fights, the term bull stands as the opposite of
>   bears.
>
> (For further reading, see Surviving Bear Country and Digging Deeper
>   Into Bull And Bear Markets, as well as The Bulls, The Bears and The
>   Farm.)